# Submitting Canvas Drawing in Flask Form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, canvas

I have created form in Flask and I am using bootstrap to help render the file. My form is working properly, but now I want to let the user draw their signature and have that signature be submitted with the form. But I have been having difficulty achieving this because when I place the canvas tag within the form tag, the user is not able to draw anything in the canvas. If I place the canvas tag outside the form tag, I am able to draw on it.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'wtf.html' as wtf %}
<html>
<body>
{% block app_content %}
{% block content %}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var flag, dot_flag = false,
        prevX, prevY, currX, currY = 0,
        color = 'black', thickness = 2;
      var $canvas = $('#canvas');
      var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');

      $canvas.on('mousemove mousedown mouseup mouseout', function(e) {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - $canvas.offset().left;
        currY = e.clientY - $canvas.offset().top;
        if (e.type == 'mousedown') {
          flag = true;
        }
        if (e.type == 'mouseup' || e.type == 'mouseout') {
          flag = false;
        }
        if (e.type == 'mousemove') {
          if (flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
            ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            ctx.lineWidth = thickness;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
          }
        }
      });

      $('.canvas-clear').on('click', function(e) {
        c_width = $canvas.width();
        c_height = $canvas.height();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c_width, c_height);
        $('#canvasimg').hide();
      });
    });
</script>

  //When canvas placed here, the canvas shows up, and it works fine as user can write to it
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="50" style="border:2px solid;"></canvas>
  <input type="button" value="Clear" class="canvas-clear" />

  <script>
        function delete_flash(flash){$(flash).parent().remove()}
  </script>

    <div class="container">
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for category, message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}" role="alert" onclick=delete_flash(this)>
                {{ message }}
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
    </div>

    <h1><center>Visitor Check In</center></h1>
    <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        <h5> &emsp;<b>3. </b>{{ form.question1.label }}</h5>
        {% for subfield in form.question1%}
            <tr>&emsp;
                <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
                <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td> &emsp;
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.question1.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}


        <h5>&emsp;<b>4. </b>{{ form.question2.label }}</h5>
        {% for subfield in form.question2%}
            <tr>&emsp;
                <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
                <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td> &emsp;
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.question2.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
        {% endfor %}


        //When canvas placed here, the canvas shows up, but user cannot write anything to it
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="50" style="border:2px solid;"></canvas>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" class="canvas-clear" />
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe the issue with putting the canvas inside the form tag is that I don't have anything in the backend to submit what is drawn on the canvas. So I was also wondering how I might be able to save what is draw to the canvas when the user clicks the submit button.